# Overall build progress Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to see the overall build progress in Visual studio?
In my solution there are nearly more than 30 projects. So it takes a long time to build the entire project.

I am looking for a way to see 8/30 In progress or something similar to that?

Answer (score 5):

It still doesn't tell you progress, but it might help to see the Build Output window.  If you know the order of the projects it should give you a feel of how far along the build is.

[image]

You can also investigate this Build Progress plugin (leverages the Windows 7 progress taskbar: https://github.com/alastairs/buildprogress/ discussed here http://www.codebork.com/coding/2009/11/04/creating-small-visual-studio-2010-add.html

Comment: If you take the Build Progress plugin code you can put together something that shows 8/30 (though the progress bar already shows you that).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the output window stuff. Also I am not using windows 7, so I won't have any luck there as well.

Comment: @gordanvij, you can use the source code from the Build Progress plugin to generate your progress indicator (w/o the W7 bits)

Comment: I would like to find this as a feature in Visual Studio rather than spending my time on it. Anyway, thanks for the reply and for giving a direction on this, much appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is quite nice extension for Visual Studio:

**VSBuildStatus:**
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2A2293B4-1808-44AA-B030-661F6803D8A1?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: Thanks, Looks very promising, will be very helpful I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Taskbar Build Progress](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5015fa55-9385-462b-bc96-2837ea0e17c6/) displays total build progress into taskbar without adding any more clutter to VS.